# Installed waha-system-adjustments_all.deb this did take over several places of my system

Tags: apt

I accidentally installed `waha-system-adjustments all.deb` from Sourceforge, which changed my Synaptic sources. I cannot get rid of it am not able to update or upgrade, what should I do?

```
dom@dom:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.8.0-35-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:25:33 UTC 2013
dom@dom:~$ cat  /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=WahaLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=7.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarab
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Waha Linux 7.2 Sarab"
dom@dom:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for dom: 
Get:1 http://sf.net sarab Release.gpg [490 B]
Hit http://sf.net sarab Release
```

Comment: What is the exact URL of the download? What version of Ubuntu have you been running?

Comment: This is not an answer as such, but I can't post as comment because of lack of reps. Hope you'll find it helpful. You can get a list of all the installed softwares and can later reinstall them.
Follow this tutorial http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages Dont forget to remove this particular application, before reinstalling all of them from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the package without installing, and it won all the red marks. It replaces almost all the most important files for any Debian distro without regards. Here's the main problem:

```
cat debian/postinst
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -d /usr/share/waha/adjustments/ ]; then
    cp -R /usr/share/waha/adjustments/* /
fi

exit 0
```

it tells that all the files in `/usr/share/waha/adjustments/` are copied to the root of the filesystem without checking before hand and no way to remove them securely. The best option is just to backup everything and reinstall the system.

List of files that get replace **without previous confirmation**:

```
/lib/live/config.sh
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux/changelog.py
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/add-ar-keyboard.mo
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/check-live-installer.mo
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/WahaLinux.py
/usr/share/waha/check-live-installer
/usr/share/waha/add-ar-keyboard
/usr/share/icons/debian-installer-launcher.png
/usr/share/icons/gnome ## several logos and svg files
/usr/share/images/desktop-base
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-wallpaper_1920x1200.svg
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-wallpaper_1280x1024.svg
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-inksplat-wallpaper_1920x1080.svg
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-wallpaper_1600x1200.svg
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/login-background.svg
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-grub.png
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-wallpaper_1920x1080.svg
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/uninstaller.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
/usr/share/applications/debian-installer-launcher.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-base.desktop
/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/usr/share/applications/wine-winetricks.desktop
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
/usr/share/applications/wine.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop
/usr/share/applications/wine-browsedrive.desktop
/usr/share/applications/supertux.desktop
/usr/share/applications/winecfg.desktop
/usr/share/applications/show-desktop.desktop
/usr/share/pyshared/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux
/usr/share/pyshared/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/UpdateManager/DistSpecific/WahaLinux/changelog.py
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.gschema.xml
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/schemas/gschemas.compiled
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/prefs.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/extension.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/myDash.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/convenience.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/stylesheet.css
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/intellihide.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/dockedDash.js
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/metadata.json
/usr/share/python-apt
/usr/share/python-apt/templates
/usr/share/python-apt/templates/WahaLinux.info
/usr/share/python-apt/templates/WahaLinux.mirrors
/etc/skel/ #most of the skel files
/etc/apt/sources.list ## Important
/etc/apt/sources.list~
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sarab.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/iceweasel-release.list
/etc/apt/preferences.d
/etc/apt/preferences.d/wheezy-backports
/etc/samba
/etc/samba/smb.conf
/etc/gdm3
/etc/gdm3/greeter.gsettings
/etc/alternatives
/etc/alternatives/start-here-48.png
/etc/alternatives/start-here.svg
/etc/alternatives/start-here-22.png
/etc/alternatives/start-here-256.png
/etc/alternatives/start-here-24.png
/etc/alternatives/start-here-32.png
/etc/alternatives/start-here-16.png
/etc/network
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
/etc/adduser.conf
/etc/lsb-release
/etc/NetworkManager
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
/etc/issue
/etc/xdg
/etc/xdg/autostart
/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs.desktop
/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-store.desktop
/etc/issue.net
```

Comment: thanks a lot is there any other way to get rid of that, i have so many software installed

Comment: helo i have been running the artistx ubuntu 13.04, never could upgraqde to 13.10,but was running good till... the mistake came with this deb http://fr.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_waha/releases/ http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_waha/ help